# Eager loading of /app folder in production - how to disable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

Is there a way to exclude a specific folder inside of /app from being eagerly loaded in production?

E.g., I use a folder called /app/components - and I don't want it to be eagerly loaded.

Comment: I'm just curious could you describe it why? :)

Comment: My specific problem is that I18n is not yet ready when the classes in /app get eagerly evaluated.

Comment: Ok, I realized why I18n wasn't meant to be used on class level: classes get cached, but the locale should be possible to change on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.eager_load_paths -= ["#{config.root}/app/components"]
```